# React animation not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a `Notification` class to manage creating/removing Notifications from the UI. I can successfully show/hide notifications, but the notifications do not animate in/out.

```
import React from 'react'
import addons from 'react/addons'

const ReactCSSTransitionGroup = React.addons.CSSTransitionGroup

let id = 0
export default class Notification {

  constructor (content, className) {

    let div = document.createElement('div')
    document.body.appendChild(div)

    let onClose = () => React.unmountComponentAtNode(div)

    React.render(
      <NotificationElement className={ className } id={ id++ } onClose={ onClose }>
        { content }
      </NotificationElement>,
      div
    )

  }

}

class NotificationElement extends React.Component {

  constructor(_) {
    super(_)
  }

  render() {

    const className = `Notification ${ this.props.className }`

    return (
      <ReactCSSTransitionGroup transitionName="slideIn">
        <div className={ className } key={ this.props.id }>
          { this.props.children }
          <a className="close-button" onClick={ this.props.onClose }>&times;</a>
        </div>
      </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
    )

  }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ReactCSSTransitionGroup` will only animate its children when they are added or removed from its `props`. In your case, the `children` prop of your `ReactCSSTransitionGroup` never changes.

Here's an example of what you could do instead:

```
let notificationsContainer = document.createElement('div');
document.body.appendChild(notificationsContainer);

let notifications = [];
function renderNotifications() {
  React.render(<Notifications notifications={notifications} />, notificationsContainer);
}

class Notifications extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <ReactCSSTransitionGroup transitionName="slideIn">
        {this.props.notifications.map(notification =>
          <NotificationElement
            key={ notification.id }
            className={ notification.className }
            onClose={ notification.onClose }
            children={ content }
            />
        )}
      </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
    );
  }

}

let id = 0
export default class Notification {

  constructor (content, className) {

    let notification = {
      id: id++, content, className,
    };

    notification.onClose = () => {
      notifications.splice(notifications.indexOf(notification), 1);
      renderNotifications();
    };

    notifications.push(notification);
    renderNotifications();

  }

}

class NotificationElement extends React.Component {

  constructor(_) {
    super(_)
  }

  render() {

    const className = `Notification ${ this.props.className }`

    return (
      <div className={ className }>
        { this.props.children }
        <a className="close-button" onClick={ this.props.onClose }>&times;</a>
      </div>
    )

  }

}
```

Every time a notification is added or removed, its corresponding element is added or removed from the `children` prop of `ReactCSSTransitionGroup`, which can then animate it in or out properly.

Answer (score 2):

You can add `transitionAppear={true}` to your `<ReactCSSTranstionGroup />` to make it animate the initial render.

It is disabled by default: https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/src/addons/transitions/ReactCSSTransitionGroup.js#L38

Comment: unfortunately that doesn't fix the issue